# Align icons and images to right, textarea to left (twitter-Bootstrap)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**TL;DR** : Before you read anything, the desired end-result is illustrated in the image below, otherwise refer to the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9SZhs/). **Preferably**, I would like to only use CSS and not modify the DOM structure.

The icons must be aligned completely to the right (hence the `.pull-right`), but the icons must be **stacked vertically** (Sometimes some icons must not appear, so they are `.hidden`, like the `.fa-undo` icon in the second row).

*(When I say 'the icons' i mean the `<i>` tags and the `<img>` tag)*

The icons must not make the textarea go down (no margin on top of the textarea).

Hopefully, the WIDTH of the textarea would be dynamic and not statically put to `width: 90%;` for example. It should take as much width as possible, without interfering with the vertical icon stack.

Here is the end result that I want (in a perfect world this would be done using CSS and the same HTML DOM I provided)

[image: The layout I want (made in paint)]

Comment: Not possible without changing the DOM. First you want three of four items react different to the last one and those also should react different to each other. Best solution would be to add a wrapping `<div>` which contains the icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed here : http://jsfiddle.net/QTXxp/2/

What was lacking when I asked this question was the `clear:right;` and the use of `<div>` (or `display: block;`)

Here is the CSS (if you're too lazy to open the JSFiddle) with the addition of the boostrap class `pull-right` on the div.icons

```
textarea.hover-edit {
    width: 90% !important;
}

div.icons {
    width: 10% !important;
}

div.icons > div > i.fa {
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-right: 4px;
}

div.icons > div.action-icon-right {
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, images that are UI elements, and not content, should be CSS backgrounds, not inline images. You then use class names to control the image content.

You should be doing this, or something similar:

```
td.fr {
   background-image:url(/images/fr.gif);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position: top right;
}
```

The same should go for your buttons. Use `<button>` and style the background.

Comment: Thanks for the 'best-practices' comment, it is appreciated, however this does not answer my problem, unfortunately.

Comment: float:left on the textarea, float:right on the buttons.

Comment: If you look at the JSFiddle, you can see that it already is the case (float:right for buttons), I tried float:left on the textarea and it doesn't change anything. If you somehow manage to produce the desired result, let me know (that's what JSFiddle FORK is for)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you wanted I'm afraid, but this is how I'd achieve that result:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9SZhs/2/)

```
<div class="pull-right icons">
    <img src="http://www.convertnsftopst.net/images/gb.gif" class="pull-right" />
    <i class="fa fa-reply"></i>
</div>

td .icons{
    width:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

> Here is the end result that I want (in a perfect world this would be done using CSS and the same HTML DOM I provided)

I was unable to do it without adding another pull-right container, I fear that doing it with only CSS would end up being an odd hack

Comment: Thanks joegandy! I opted for a solution pretty similar to this, but because of some other desired behavior in the application (adding columns dynamically for some rows only), and to keep the responsiveness, I have to use width % instead of PX's. I also had to use float:right and clear:right TOGETHER otherwise my solution wouldn't work.

Comment: Yep I was going to mention the px wasn't ideal, glad you sorted your issue in the end.